# Can every manifold be turned into a Lie group?

Tags: manifolds, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds

I am studying Lie theory and just thought of this random question out of curiosity. Can any manifold be turned into a Lie group?

More precisely, given a manifold $G$, can we always construct (or prove the existence of) some smooth map $m:G\times G\to G$ that makes $G$ into a Lie group? If not, is there an easy counterexample?

I could imagine a construction going something like this: pick an arbitrary point $e\in M$ to be the identity, and define $m(e,g)=m(g,e)=g$ for all $g\in G$. Then we already have the elements of the Lie algebra given as the tangent space at the identity $T_eG$, and maybe we can use these to extend $m$ to all of $G$?

Comment: So far, you've only constructed multiplication by a single element, the identity.  So you have a long way to go. `:-)` But you'll find that a Lie group must be parallelizable, and many manifolds (e.g., $S^2$) are not.

Comment: Parallelizability is the major obstacle, but there's a result from Wolf that a compact, simply-connected manifold is parallelizable iff it's the product of a Lie group and copies of $S^7$.

Comment: Somehow related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/5262/lie-groups-and-manifolds

Comment: anomaly:  Are you missing a hypothesis?  There are many more examples of parallelizable manifolds.  The simplest is probably $S^2\times S^3$.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

There is an easy counterexample: $S^2$ cannot be given a Lie group structure (this is a consequence of the hairy ball theorem). The problem with your construction is that it doesn't offer how to define $m(g,h)$ for any two nonidentity elements $g$ and $h$.

Answer (score 28):

Lie groups as manifolds, are very special, owing to the group operations. Basically, "what happens at the identity" determines what happens everywhere. And this means that the tangent bundle $T G$ is always trivializable: here is a sketch of the proof, based on what I remember from [Lee's book](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-0-387-21752-9).

Take any basis $\{v_i\}^n_{i=1}$ for $T_eG$. Since left multiplication $L_g:G\to G:h\mapsto gh$ is a diffeomorphism, it induces an isomorphism $dL_g:T_eG\to T_gG.$ Now, define vector fields $\{V_i\}^n_{i=1}$ by $(V_i)_g:=dL_g(v_i)$and show that they are smooth. Then, since $dL_g$ is an isomorphism, $\{dL_g(v_i)\}^n_{i=1}$ is a basis for $T_gG$, so the vector fields $\{V_i\}^n_{i=1}$ are a global frame for $TG$.

Comment: Can you add a final sentence along the lines that this shows that $S^2$ cannot be made into a Lie group because this would imply the existence of a nowhere vanishing vector field which doesn't exist by the hairy ball theorem.

Comment: I'm not sure how this relates to my question, other than being about Lie groups.

Comment: If every manifold could be realized as a Lie group then every manifold would have a trivial tangent bundle, which is not true, as the other answers and comments point out.

Comment: @quarague  I guess your comment is enough ...+1

Answer (score 24):

To add to the previous answers, topological groups have abelian fundamental groups.

[$G$ is Topological $\implies$ $\pi_1(G,e)$ is Abelian](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/727999/g-is-topological-implies-pi-1g-e-is-abelian)

Orientable surfaces of genus at least two are not parallelizable, but this is another way to show that they can't be Lie (even topological) groups. The Klein bottle is parallelizable (**edit: no it's not**), but its fundamental group is not abelian, so it can't be a group either.

Comment: The Klein bottle is non-orientable, so the tangent bundle is nontrivial.

Comment: @JasonDeVito you're right, oops!

Answer (score 15):

The answers so far are great, but I wanted to add some more obstructions.  Suppose $M$ is a manifold which can be given the structure of a Lie group.  Then $M$ has the following properties...

1. $\pi_1(M)$ acts trivially on $\pi_n(M)$
2. Each $\pi_n(M)$ is finitely generated.
3. $\pi_2(M) = 0$.
4. $\pi_{2k}(M)$ is a finite abelian group for all $k\geq 1$.
5. $\pi_3(M)$ contains no torsion.
6. If $M$ is compact, then at least one of $\pi_1(M)$ and $\pi_3(M)$ contains $\mathbb{Z}$ as a subroup.
7. If $M$ is non-compact, then $M$ must be diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^k\times N$ for some compact Lie group $N$.
8. If $M$ is simply connected, then it can only torsion of order $2$, $3$, or $5$ in its cohomology groups.

There are still many manifolds which pass all these obstructions (as well as all the obstructions in the other answers!) - for example, $M = S^3\times S^5$.  However, this $M$ isn't a Lie group (though the only way I know to show this is using the classification.  It's simply connected and dimension $8$, so the only Lie group $M$ could be diffeomorphic to is $SU(3)$.  However, $\pi_4(M) = \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ while $\pi_4(SU(3)) = 0$.)

Comment: Do you have a reference for where I can read about these properties? I've never heard of most of these but am very interested.

Comment: The tangent bundle of $S^5$ isn't trivializable -- there is only one linearly independent vector field on $S^5$. This is a direct way to see that $S^3\times S^5$ is not a Lie group. (A famous result of Adams computed the number of linearly dependent vector fields on spheres.)

Comment: @Hood:  $S^5$ is not parallelizable, but $S^3 \times S^5$ is.  More generally, a product of $n\geq 2$ spheres is parallelizable iff at least one of the spheres is odd dimensional.  See, e.g. https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1967-018-03/S0002-9939-1967-0219082-6/S0002-9939-1967-0219082-6.pdf

Comment: @kamills:  For 1 and 4, Algebraic Models in Geometry by Felix, Oprea, and Tanre has the results (but maybe not the proofs).  2 is a general fact of algebraic topology and applies to anything (and more) satisfying 1.  The key word is "simple space".  3 and 5 can be found in Milnor's Morse Theory book.  6 works as follows:  if $\pi_1(M)$ doesn't contain a $\mathbb{Z}$, then finite generation implies $\pi_1(M)$ is finite, so the universal cover of $M$, $\hat{M}$ is a simply connected compact Lie group.  Then $H^3(\hat{M};\mathbb{R})\neq 0$, which can be seen using the bi-invariant form...

Comment: $\omega(x,y,z) = \langle [x,y],z\rangle$ where $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ is a bi-invariant metric on $\hat{M}$ and $x,y,z$ are left invariant vector fields.  It then follows that $H^3(\hat{M})$ contains $ \mathbb{Z}$.  Now use Hurewicz (noting that $\pi_1(\hat{M}) = \pi_2(\hat{M} = 0$).  7. Is called the Iwasa decomposition.  I don't study/use non-compact Lie groups, so I don't know of a reference (also, you may need to assume $M$ is connected for 7 to be true...).  Finally, 8 follows from the classification of simply connected Lie groups:  $M$ must be isomorphic to a product with ...

Comment: factors of the form $SU(n)$, $Spin(n)$, $Sp(n)$ (where $n$ can vary) or factors of the form $G_2, F_4, E_6, E_7, E_8$.  But the torsion in each case is $2,3,$ or $5$-torsion.

Comment: @JasonDeVito Makes sense, thanks!

Comment: @JasonDeVito Thanks so much!

Answer (score 7):

As many people are giving intersting counterexamples I thought I should also add one .
Any surface( compact orientable hausdorff 2 manifold) with non zero Euler characteristics cannot be a Lie group because from standard theorem in differential topology , Euler's characteristic of compact orientable lie group is zero. For instance it's 2 for 2 sphere so it can't be a Lie group.

Answer (score 7):

If $G$ is a Lie group, then $G$ is *homogeneous*, meaning that for any $g,h\in G$, there is a diffeomorphism $F:G\to G$ such that $F(g)=h$, namely $F(x)=hg^{-1}x$.  This gives an easy way to find manifolds that cannot be Lie groups.  For instance, let $G$ be the disjoint union of $\mathbb{R}$ and $S^1$.  Then no diffeomorphism of $G$ can map a point of $S^1$ to a point of $\mathbb{R}$ (since a diffeomorphism must preserve the property of being in a compact connected component), so $G$ cannot be a Lie group.

(Note though that actually any connected manifold is homogeneous, whereas most connected manifolds do not admit a Lie group structure.  So admitting a Lie group structure is actually much stronger than just being homogeneous.)

Comment: So I guess the question would be more interesting if it were about connected manifolds only.

Comment: Right.  But you asked for an easy counterexample, and this is the easiest one I think!